# Gson outputting com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 501

Tags: java, android, json

I've been using Gson to parse JSON in an API to use in my app. This is an example of the JSON output:

```
{"getdashboarddata":{"version":"1.0.0","runtime":492.3939704895,"data":{"raw":{"personal":{"hashrate":0},"pool":{"hashrate":1705841},"network":{"hashrate":41430764.301,"esttimeperblock":94.464466565347,"nextdifficulty":578.78109116,"blocksuntildiffchange":1}},"personal":{"hashrate":0,"sharerate":"0.0000","sharedifficulty":0,"shares":{"valid":0,"invalid":0,"invalid_percent":0,"unpaid":0},"estimates":{"block":0,"fee":0,"donation":0,"payout":0}},"pool":{"info":{"name":"RAPIDHASH","currency":"DOGE"},"workers":2199,"hashrate":1.705841,"shares":{"valid":1866290,"invalid":15564,"invalid_percent":0.83,"estimated":1866214,"progress":100},"price":"0.00000073","difficulty":32,"target_bits":21},"system":{"load":[0.1,0.25,0.29]},"network":{"hashrate":41.430764301,"difficulty":911.23745057,"block":235378,"esttimeperblock":94.46,"nextdifficulty":578.78109116,"blocksuntildiffchange":1}}}}
```

This is the logcat:

```
05-25 17:12:00.230  24143-24159/io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker, PID: 24143
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 501
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
        at io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77)
        at io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:64)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 501
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1377)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:471)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.skipValue(JsonReader.java:1209)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
            at io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77)
            at io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:64)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

This is the code that gets and parses the JSON:

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            String resp = null;
            try {
                resp =  downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                resp = "{\"getdashboarddata\":{\"data\":{\"personal\":{\"hashrate\":0},\"pool\":{\"info\":{\"name\":\"SET POOL IN SETTINGS\",\"currency\":\"???\"},\"hashrate\":0,\"difficulty\":0},\"network\":{\"hashrate\":0,\"difficulty\":0}}}}";
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Log.d("INFO", resp);
            MPOSDashStruct data = gson.fromJson(resp, MPOSDashStruct.class);
            TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.poolName);
            TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.khashMe);
            TextView t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.khashPool);
            TextView t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.khashNet);
            t.setText(data.getName());
            t2.setText(data.getMyHash());
            t3.setText(data.getPoolHash());
            t4.setText(data.getNetHash());
            return "Hello World. If you see this, you probably hack. Get out.";
        }

        private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = null;
            // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
            // web page content.
            int len = 500;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                is = conn.getInputStream();

                // Convert the InputStream into a string
                String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
                return contentAsString;

                // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
                // finished using it.
            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }

        public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            Reader reader = null;
            reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
            char[] buffer = new char[len];
            reader.read(buffer);
            return new String(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the class MPOSDashStruct:

```
package io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by George on 25/05/2014.
 */
public class MPOSDashStruct {
    public static class getdashboarddata {
        public static class data {
            public static class personal {
                public static int hashrate;
            }
            public static class pool {
                public static int hashrate;
                public static int difficulty;
                public static class info {
                    @SerializedName("name")
                    public static String poolName;
                    public static String currency;
                }
            }
            public static class network {
                public static int hashrate;
                public static int difficulty;
            }
        }
    }
    public String getName() {
        return getdashboarddata.data.pool.info.poolName;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return getdashboarddata.data.pool.info.currency;
    }

    public int getPoolHash() {
        return getdashboarddata.data.pool.hashrate;
    }

    public int getPoolDiff() {
        return getdashboarddata.data.pool.difficulty;
    }

    public int getMyHash() {
        return getdashboarddata.data.personal.hashrate;
    }

    public int getNetHash() {
        return getdashboarddata.data.network.hashrate;
    }
}
```

The code is seemingly good, and Android Studio has no errors.

EDIT 2: contentAsString ouputs

```
05-25 17:30:12.976  29974-29988/io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker D/INFO﹕ {"getdashboarddata":{"version":"1.0.0","runtime":632.7919960022,"data":{"raw":{"personal":{"hashrate":0},"pool":{"hashrate":1675289},"network":{"hashrate":38541151.201,"esttimeperblock":61.161346587453,"nextdifficulty":538.41366248,"blocksuntildiffchange":1}},"personal":{"hashrate":0,"sharerate":"0.0000","sharedifficulty":0,"shares":{"valid":0,"invalid":0,"invalid_percent":0,"unpaid":0},"estimates":{"block":0,"fee":0,"donation":0,"payout":0}},"pool":{"info":{"name":"RAPIDHASH","currency":"DOGE"}
```

using Log.d("INFO", contentAsString)

EDIT: After using getContentLength, the new logcat is this:

```
05-25 17:50:19.203    5143-5157/io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bd4ba8)
05-25 17:50:19.203    5143-5157/io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker, PID: 5143
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
            at io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.readIt(MainActivity.java:120)
            at io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.downloadUrl(MainActivity.java:104)
            at io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:71)
            at io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:64)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

which points to this line of my code:

```
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            Reader reader = null;
            reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
            char[] buffer = new char[len]; //this line, others added so you can understand
            reader.read(buffer);
            return new String(buffer);
        }
```

EDIT 3: Directing Gson to handle the Reader worked well, but new errors arise again. Logcat:

```
05-26 09:17:52.459  11810-11810/io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker, PID: 11810
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker/io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at io.kd.figgycity50.mpos.mposchecker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

which points to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String prefPool = sharedPref.getString("pref_pool", "https://doge.rapidhash.net/");
        String prefKey = sharedPref.getString("pref_key", "XXXX");
        new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(prefPool + "index.php?page=api&action=getdashboarddata&api_key=" + prefKey);
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.poolName); // this line
        TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.khashMe);
        TextView t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.khashPool);
        TextView t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.khashNet);
        t.setText(dashStruct.getName());
        t2.setText(dashStruct.getMyHash());
        t3.setText(dashStruct.getPoolHash());
        t4.setText(dashStruct.getNetHash());
    }
```

Comment: Have you printed out `contentAsString`? Is your response UTF8?

Comment: I don't know if the response is UTF8, as it's not my API. I edited the output of contentAsString when using Log.d with it in the post, as it's too long for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Edit 3` above, the following line seems to be throwing the `NullPointerException`:

```
t.setText(dashStruct.getName());
```

I can tell that you declare `dashStruct` as a class level variable which is getting initialized in the AsyncTask `DownloadWebpageTask`.

By design, an AsyncTask will be executed off the main thread (to be precise, the AsyncTask#doInBackground(T) method). If `DownloadWebpageTask` hasn't finished initializing `dashStruct` when the main thread executes `t.setText(dashStruct.getName());` - an NPE will be thrown - `dashStruct` is null.

To get past this exception, override `onPostExecute()` in `DownloadWebpageTask` and move the following code to it (remove it from `onCreate(Bundle)`):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (dashStruct != null) {
        t.setText(dashStruct.getName());
        t2.setText(dashStruct.getMyHash());
        t3.setText(dashStruct.getPoolHash());
        t4.setText(dashStruct.getNetHash());
    } else {
        // Deal with dashStruct being null
    }
}
```

I notice that in your original posting, you are updating your UI (setting textview text) from the `DownloadWebpageTask#doInBackground(String...)`. This will throw an `IllegalStateException` as `doInBackground()` is processed off the main thread - the only thread allowed to touch your UI. `onPostExecute()` is processed on the main thread. And that's where your UI logic should go.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you do this

```
// Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
// web page content.
int len = 500;
```

If your JSON is longer than that, you're breaking it into pieces that are not parseable by JSON parsers. Read the full JSON string.

Get the [content length](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) from the response.

```
int len = conn.getContentLength();
```

Comment: @user2758631 Ah, it's possible that the method returns -1 if the header does not exist in the response. A solution here is to pass the `InputStream` directly to `Gson` instead of reading it as a `String` first.

Comment: After doing that, there's a new error, but not in the DownloadWebpageTask. See edit for logcat.